# Upon the wife's request during an argument, if a man gives his wife three talaqs at once, are they divorced?

Tags: talaq

I would like to know that in an argument between husband and wife, if a woman says to her husband "leave me", then "divorce me" and the husband replies back "are you sure?" and he gives her 3 talaqs at once. Is that considered as full 3 talaqs or qulla (khul') talaq.

We both are Sunnis.

And if it is not, please can you provide proof in Quran and hadiths.

Many are saying different things and I am very confused.

Comment: What is 'Qulla talaq'?

Comment: It is when a woman asks for divorce

Comment: Also there was 1 male witness to this

Comment: Khul' is made by a court if a woman ask for talaq. Talaq is given by the husband.

Answer (score 2):

Khula (Qulla) is when wife goes to court and court dissolves the marriage. Husband does not have to utter divorce in the case of Khula. If the husband said the words, it is a talaq divorce even if he did so upon his wife's request.

As for if it is one or three talaqs, there is a difference of opinion between  Sunni schools of thoughts. Some say if you utter I give you three talaqs, it will be considered 3. Others do not agree and consider it one iteration of talaq. You will have to do your own research on what school of thought you follow and what their opinion on this regard is, or perhaps ask your local imam.

Moral of the story is that it is never a good idea to utter 3 talaqs when uttering it once will suffice.